# how to fast redrawing an image buffer

Tags: c, gtk, cairo, xorg

I'm developing some kind of audio-application where I need to display some graphs. Think: realtime Oscillope-like images at a high framerate.

All I need is to display some graphics buffer at a high framerate. Preferably >60fps without taking much time. The way I've implemented it right now is too slow. I can only get 10fps with a resolution of 800x800 pixels. The drawing is not the problem, Xorg is taking all the time.

The method I use now is that I create a `cairo_image_surface` and then manipulate the data in the `cairo_images_surface` at the pixels that need to change (which is quite fast)

Because I'm programming something like an oscilloscope I don't need to redraw all the pixels all the time. So drawing things isn't very slow.

The slow part I think is that I need to call `cairo_set_source_surface()` to actually display something.

a summary of the most important parts of the code. `on_plot_event` is called everytime there's a new audiosample ready for display.

```
static gboolean on_plot_event(GtkWidget *widget,cairo_t *cr,gpointer user_data){
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr,crsurfplot,0,0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    return FALSE;
}

int doplot(jack_default_audio_sample_t *in,jack_nframes_t nframes){
    cairo_surface_flush(crsurfplot);
    char *p;
    unsigned char *pixstart;
    pixstart = plotdata;
 //drawing stuff, manipulate pixels at pixstart
    cairo_surface_mark_dirty(crsurfplot);
    if(drawcount%10 ==0){
    gdk_threads_enter();
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(window);
    gdk_threads_leave();
    }
}


int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    gdk_threads_init();
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    window2 = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    plotstride = cairo_format_stride_for_width (CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,plotwidth);
    plotdata = malloc (16000000);
    crsurfplot = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data    (plotdata,CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,plotwidth,plotheight,plotstride);
    plotdata = cairo_image_surface_get_data(crsurfplot);    

    plot = gtk_drawing_area_new();  
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),plot);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(plot),"draw",G_CALLBACK(on_plot_event),NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(plot),"configure-event",G_CALLBACK(on_confev),NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_widget_show (window2);
    printf("test\n");

    crplot=gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(plot));
    cairo_set_source_surface(crplot,crsurfplot,0,0);

    gtk_main ();

    jack_client_close(client);
    return 0;

}
```

Is it impossible to create the thing I want with Cairo? Should I use openGL or something like that instead? Or am I just doing something wrong?

edit: added link to my ugly program thus far. 
http://ubuntuone.com/4dphKneXOgQPTR8fZydKpo

Comment: Please, provide a test program that compiles. BTW, the doplot function is never called here, but seems to use some thread locking. Are you using threads? And yes, 60fps is doable with cairo. Give a look at clipping functions, you most probably draw more than required.

Answer (score 1):

> The method I use now is that I create a cairo_image_surface and then manipulate the data in the cairo_images_surface at the pixels that need to change (which is quite fast)
>
> Because I'm programming something like an oscilloscope I don't need to redraw all the pixels all the time. So drawing things isn't very slow.

I would disagree in 99.9% of graphic applications I have encountered (larger displays and frame rates) it is faster to redraw the picture in background with all the intricate sprites, bars, etc. and than flip it all at once. Even though this sounds counter-intuitive, I propose, you should try this

---

Cairo should be able to handle what U want.

Comment: Well, the creation of the surface only happens on initialization. But it's not the drawing of the image-buffer which takes the time, it's displaying it. When I comment out the `cairo_set_source_surface` then there's almost no CPU usage anymore.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by redrawing in the background and flipping...

Comment: @user2237652 "Redrawing and flipping" is a reference to [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics), a pretty common graphics technique.

Answer (score 0):

It might be faster to use cairo_surface_create_similar_image() instead of creating a fresh image surface. This allows cairo to use shared memory which should speed up the upload of the image a lot.

(Also, of course it is way faster when you do not call cairo_set_source_surface(): In this case cairo doesn't have to upload the image surface but can just tell the X11 server "fill everything with black")

Also, why the following? Just use cairo_image_surface_create() instead of calling malloc() and ...create_for_data().

```
plotdata = malloc (16000000);
crsurfplot = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data    (plotdata,CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,plotwidth,plotheight,plotstride);
plotdata = cairo_image_surface_get_data(crsurfplot);
```

Comment: The malloc part is because otherwise things go wrong when resizing the window.

Comment: So I can do without cairo_set_source_surface() to refresh the screen? Because without it, the screen doesn't update. There is probably another way of telling cairo to repaint that surface, which I don't know about.    The malloc part is because otherwise things go wrong when resizing the window. I'll have to implement that in a better way, but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off `GtkWidget`'s double buffering system for your drawing area may help.

```
gtk_widget_set_double_buffered (GTK_WIDGET (plot), FALSE);
```

This will stop Gtk introducing an intermediate step before your image is drawn to the window.

[gtk_widget_set_double_buffered documentation](http://people.gnome.org/~shaunm/girdoc/C/Gtk.Widget.set_double_buffered.html)